# Middy with TypeScript, callback type

Tags: typescript, middy

I'm trying to use TyepScript witn `Middy` on a Lambda API call.
Part of my code:

```
// My types definition
import BodyRequestType from 'types';

// some code

async function myFunction (
  event: { body: BodyRequestType },
  callback: ??? <--
): Promise<void> {
  // my code
  return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
}

export const handler = middy(myFunction);
```

I tried to use:

```
import { Callback } from 'aws-lambda'
// then...
callback: Callback
```

But I get this error on `middy(myFunction)`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(event: { body: BodyRequestType; }, callback: Callback<any>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'AsyncHandler<Context>'.
Type '(event: { body: BodyRequestType; }, callback: Callback<any>) => Promise<void>'
is not assignable to type '(event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback<any>) => void'.
Types of parameters 'callback'and 'context' are incompatible.
Type 'Context' is not assignable to type 'Callback<any>'.
Type 'Context' provides no match for the signature '(error?: string | Error | null | undefined, result?: any): void'.
```

What type should I use on `callback` argument of myFunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 2nd argument is supposed to be `Context` type in its signature instead of the callback.

Since context is required so you just set `context` and `callback` as 2nd, 3rd argument respectively as following:

```js
import { Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';


async function myFunction (
  event: { body: BodyRequestType },
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback 
) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I give up like 30 minutes ago and put `any` while focus in other things, I then I read that the order for those arguments were important... ...and also for types, thanks man!

Comment: There is a tip is to read the type definition directly in the package would help you a lot